# How to design granular permissions (authorization) in NodeJS (express)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, authorization, jwt

I'm trying to implement fine grained / granular permissions on users in my REST API (expressjs / mysql).

My web application contains **member groups**.
Each **member group** has a single administrator (user).

I don't think JWT would work here because when claims are stored in a users JWT token, if the administrator of the group changes, then the old user might still have a claim on their token thats invalid.

For example:

user1 becomes administrator of group g1

user1 has token1 which allows admin actions on group g1.

user2 becomes the new administrator of group g1.

user1's token is still valid and contains claims which allows admin actions on group1.

How do I go about implementing a per-object level authorization mechanism in nodejs where a user -> performs action -> on object?

PassportJS handles authentication but im unable to find good information about implementing authorization with the above complexity.

Does it make sense to store the permissions information in a database and query the database and perform authorization validations?

Comment: I would get user rights from database at login and keep them on server side session with express-session on redis etc, and build routing system on that. Express has a great middleware system, so you can put your own authorization middlewares including your validations, before your objects. But design your system first on claims, you know Claim Based Auth needs detailed rights to each object.

Comment: What happens when a claim is invalid or expired in the database even though the token allows a user to do something dangerous?

Comment: you can setup heartbeat system for sessions to update claims on session and another middleware for flagged users

Comment: is there a simpler way to approach this problem? @serifcetiner it seems easier to check the database in the middleware for special endpoints that require it rather than implement flag checking of users across all endpoints. Also maintaining the flags in cache or database might be more complicated?

Comment: yes it is more complicated but checking db for all requests makes your system slower. if you have less users and less requests checking db just fine